# Equivalence (Or non-equivalence) of definitions for Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

So, I've stumbled across a definition of a metric space that has given me some pause. The definition of a Metric Space that I've always used has been the following:

> A **Metric Space** is a set $X$ together with a function $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the standard metric axioms.

However, while reading Munkres' *Topology*, he presents the following definition of a metric space:

A **Metric Space** is a metrizable space $X$ together with some specific metric $d$ that gives the topology of $X$.

The reason this definition has given me pause is not only the fact that I've never seen it but that the first definition of a metric space has no assumption that $X$ must be metrizable. In fact, it doesn't even assume $X$ is a topological space. Now, of course, with a metric $d$ on $X$, we may equip $X$ with the metric topology induced by $d$ and *make* $X$ a topological space, but it seems to me each of the two definitions require us to know quite different things about $X$ before calling it a metric space. The first definition seems more "bare-bones" in a sense while the second requires us to know that $X$ possesses certain kinds of structures/properties. Are these two definitions, in fact, equivalent, or if they are inequivalent, are there other reasons at play for desiring an alternative notion of a metric space?

Comment: Munkre's defintion looks somewhat convoluted, but he means exactly what the other definition says.

Comment: It would be useful to know exactly where in Munkres you find this quotation.

Comment: I'm confused. Aren't they equivalent for exactly the reason you gave, namely if you have a metric, you can make $X$ into a topological space?

Comment: @LeeMosher Munkres' definition is given in section 20 of his book (his introduction to the metric topology). I would say it's page 118 in my copy of the book, but this might not be helpful since I know there are multiple versions floating around!

Comment: @mathworker21 What confuses me I guess is that with the first definition, if I know $d$ is a metric on a set $X$, then I know $X$ is a metric space, full stop. However, couldn't I then equip $X$ with some topology $T$ such that $(X,T)$ would not be metrizable? If I could do that then the second definition of a metric space wouldn't be satisfied while the first is.

Comment: Formally, a metric space by your first definition would be an ordered pair $(X,d)$ (and one could subsequently construct the metric topology $T$ that corresponds to $d$), whereas by your second definition it would be an ordered triple $(X,T,d)$ (and $T$ *is* the metric topology that corresponds to $d$). What I take away from this is that Munkres wishes to put the topology on equal footing with the metric $d$. I don't think this definition has been adopted by the general mathematical public. But I can see its appeal nonetheless.

Comment: @user516079 No, you can't do that. Like the second definition says, a metric space is the ordered pair $(X,d)$ where $d$ *does* give the topology on $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Your question has been answered in Lee Mosher's second comment.

The difference is that a metric space in the standard definition is a pair $(X,d)$ with a *set* $X$, whereas in Munkres' definition it is a pair $(X,d)$ with a *topological space* $X$. As Lee Mosher remarked, in the second case one should more precisely write it as a triple $(X, \mathfrak T,d)$ with a set $X$ and a topology $\mathfrak T$ on $X$.

There is a $1$-$1$-correspondence between "standard pairs" and "Munkres triples". In fact, the functions
$$(X, \mathfrak T,d) \mapsto (X,d), \\(X,d) \mapsto (X, \mathfrak T_d,d) ,$$
where $\mathfrak T_d$ is the metric topology generated by $d$, are inverse to each other. It is therefore a matter of taste which definition you prefer.

Perhaps Munkres intention is to focus on the concept of a *metrizable space*. This is a space, not a set, with a certain property. This might be also the reason why he explicitly says that a metric space is a **metrizable** space together with some specific metric $d$ that gives the topology of $X$. The word "metrizable" could of course be omitted.